My texts aren't visible, only the background image
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:theme="@style/WidgetTheme">
    <!-- ImageView for background image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <!-- Foreground content container -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="start">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:gravity="start">
            <!-- ImageView for icon -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconImage"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" 
                android:baselineAlignBottom="true"/>
            <!-- TextView for city -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cityText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Temperature TextView -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tempText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
        <!-- Description TextView -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

My texts aren't visible. I see only my background image, but the other elements are invisible.
If I use RelativeLayout everything is OK. I see all my text, but I have to use linear layout (because of the shape of my image).
What's the problem here?

You don't specify the orientation of the top LinearLayout. It is horizontal in  default. And your ImageView of @+id/backgroundImage is too big then the content of the second LinearLayout can not be seen.
You can try this.

Set android:orientation="vertical" in the top LinearLayout.
Just modify the width and height of the IamgeView

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

You can see your texts now.

But I want this image to be as background, if I set some size, then it will not be as background

@Bear You can only use LinearLayout? If so, you can set the image to the background of the top LinearLayout.
